# SQL to match closest time proceeding time between tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table 1 has sensor event data - so a time stamp column and a value column that measuring something - say the size of bumps on a stick.

Table 2 also has sensor event data so a time stamp column and a value column. Table 2's data is dependent on Table 1's data, but will have a different time stamp and number of records may not match - say table 2 is measuring speed bumps are traveling when they go through the sensor - but if there's a bunch of bumps in a short time frame it will give an average.

I'm trying to develop a query such that I get a table giving for each value in Table 1 there is a column with the value from Table 2 that has the closest subsequent time stamp from the time stamp in table 1.

Eg: Table 1

```
Time| ValueA 
1   | 5.6 
2   | 2.4 
3   | 9.7 
4   | 3.2
```

Table 2

```
Time| ValueB 
2   | 7.3 
3   | 6.4 
5   | 1.2
```

Output desired from Query:

```
Time| ValueA | ValueB 
1   | 5.6    | 7.3 
2   | 2.4    | 6.4 
3   | 9.7    | 1.2 
4   | 3.2    | 1.2
```

Comment: How is 1.2 *the closest subsequent time stamp* of 9.7?

Comment: Even you provide data as text (not image as many do) there is a loot o room for improvemnt by [formating text as table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). If you had added some not working sql code, you avoided the downvotes (for not showing own effort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select top 1 t2.value
        from table2 as t2
        where t2.time > t1.time
        order by t2.time asc
       ) as t2_value
from table1 as t1;
```